# vba paste sheet1 values and keep original source formatting?

Tags: excel, vba

I have up to 6 cells with potential data coming from 6 different places. I am trying to get only the first three cells with data transferred to another sheet WITH THE ORIGINAL FORMAT Sub Transfer_Data()

```
Sub Transfer_Data()

Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 1

For i = 1 To 6
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If

    If j > 3 Then Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

what happens is it displays the sheet2 format and color when im trying to keep sheet1

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
Sub Transfer_Data()

Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 1

For i = 1 To 6
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        j = j + 1
    End If

    If j > 3 Then Exit For
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**Edited code as per the new requirement:**

```
Sub Transfer_Data()

Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 1

For i = 1 To 6
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Interior.Color = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color
        j = j + 1
    End If

    If j > 3 Then Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: im sorry if i didnt word the question clear. i just want the color pasted not the font and format

Comment: I just tried the code on some dummy data and it worked perfectly fine. Can you upload the sample file on One drive, Google drive or Dropbox and share the link so that I can see why it is not working as desired?